# How to switch icon when user unfollows using ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have made a follow icon (button) that when a signed in user clicks it, it adds that follow to that game using ajax

I was wondering how to switch the the button icon and class. Im not really good with JavaScript, or with ajax.

Here is my button:

```
<a href="#" class="follow-game" data-game_id="<?php echo $game['id']; ?>"><i class="empty star large icon"></i></a>
```

And this is what I want it to be changed to whern user clicks on that icon:

```html
<a href="#" class="unfollow-game" data-game_id="<?php echo $game['id']; ?>"><i class="star large icon"></i></a>
```

Here is my code to follow and unfollow using ajax:

```html
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.follow-game').click(function(){
            follow_game(this);
        });
    });
    function follow_game(obj){
        var game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'follow.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                game_id : game_id
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("Followed");
            }
        });

    }


    $(function(){
        $('.unfollow-game').click(function(){
            unfollow_game(this);
        });
    });
    function unfollow_game(obj){
        var game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'unfollow.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                game_id : game_id
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("Unfollowed");
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Now that I have this figured out, I have another problem, when the signed-in user clicks follow button it turns into a filled star, BUT when the user clicks on some link and goes back, or refreshes the page, the star goes back to empty, even though that user is still following. Do you guys know any solutions to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) jquery methods:

```
function follow_game(obj){
    var game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'follow.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            game_id : game_id
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("Followed");
            $(obj).find("i").removeClass("empty")
        }
    });
}

function unfollow_game(obj){
    var game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'unfollow.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            game_id : game_id
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("Unfollowed");
            $(obj).find("i").addClass("empty");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: when you say find ("i"), you mean the class? Oh i see the i is coming from my i in user icon, woops ok

Comment: Ok Thank You for that.

Comment: I mean the HTML element `i`

Answer (score 0):

You can describe this logics in AJAX success handler.

Just replace your

```
success: function() {
    alert("Followed");
}
```

to something like this:

```
success: function() {
    $(obj).find('i').removeClass('empty'); // <-- your class
}
```

And do the reverse thing using `addClass` in your Unfollow handler.

Comment: Ok Thank You for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('.follow-game').click(function(){
                follow_game(this);
            });
        });
        function follow_game(obj){
            var game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'follow.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    game_id : game_id
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert("Followed");
                    $(obj).removeClass('follow-game');
                    $(obj).addClass('unfollow-game');
                    $(obj).find("i").removeClass("empty");
                }
            });

        }


        $(function(){
            $('.unfollow-game').click(function(){
                unfollow_game(this);
            });
        });
        function unfollow_game(obj){
            var game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'unfollow.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    game_id : game_id
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert("Unfollowed");
                    $(obj).removeClass('unfollow-game');
                    $(obj).addClass('follow-game');
                    $(obj).find("i").addClass("empty");
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```